# Distribution of multiplying discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

According to these two links,( [Link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239316/determine-the-pmf-of-the-multiplication-of-two-discrete-random-variables) and [Link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182962/probability-of-product-of-two-random-variables))
The distribution of multiplying two discrete random variables is given by :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Pr(T=t)&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x,Y=t/x)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(Y=t/x|X=x)  Pr(X=x) \\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(X=x) Pr(Y=t/x) \text{  ( if X independent Y )}
 \end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}
How the general formula will look like if there are more than two random variables ?
Similarly for the sum of two discrete random variables ( [Link3](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/07%3A_Sums_of_Random_Variables/7.01%3A_Sums_of_Discrete_Random_Variables)) is given by :
\begin{equation*}
%  \scriptsize
\begin{aligned}
Pr(Z=z)&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x,Y=z-x)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr(Y=z-x|X=x)   Pr (X=x) \\
&=\sum\limits_{x} Pr (X=x) Pr(Y=z-x) \text{  ( if X independent Y )}
 \end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}
How the general formula will look like if there are more than two random variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the general formula to get the PDF of function of random variables:

$$
p(y)=∫d^nx\, δ(F(x⃗ )−y)p(x⃗ ) 
$$

Where $F$ is the function of random variables, $x_i$ are the original random variables, $\delta$ is the diract delta, and $p(y)$ is the target PDF.

For arbitrary products you can use, $y = F(x_1,...x_n) = \prod_i x_i$ , and assuming $p(x_1,...x_n) = \prod_i p_i(x_i)$ you can get the distribution of arbitrary independent products.  Similarly for sums etc.  The integral might be tricky to do and one would have to look up properties of the dirac delta function.

For discrete variables there is a corresponding discrete delta formula.  See [Transforming Variables Using the Dirac Generalized Function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686109)
 for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: it is not continuous so we cant use integral. I am talking about discrete variables. is there a way of writing the general form in a similar way that I have written in the question?

Comment: yes, the link I put in discusses the discrete case as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it out